# What's the data type of this variable?

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Dim FilesA As String()
Dim FilesB() As String
```

What is the data type for FilesA?
What is the difference between above two declarations?
Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: This is not a question for SO. Anyone who has worked their way through a beginners tutorial knows what type that is and whether they can be used interchangeably is something that you can test for yourself.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They both are the same. They're just different kind of declaration. Both will declare an array.